# Diagnosing errors on Puppeteer running on Heroku with screenshot

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-scraping, puppeteer

I can't figure out why Puppeteer is unable to locate elements when running on Heroku that it can locate while running locally.

I'd like to try and diagnose my issue by having Puppeteer take a screenshot of the page, but I can't figure out how to retrieve the screenshot so I can see it.

Where do I go on Heroku to view the screenshot which is generated?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  let url =
    "https://www.realtor.ca/map#ZoomLevel=14&Center=43.744046%2C-79.406789&LatitudeMax=43.76832&LongitudeMax=-79.36641&LatitudeMin=43.71977&LongitudeMin=-79.44717&view=list&Sort=6-D&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&PriceMax=1500000&BuildingTypeId=1&Currency=CAD";
  await page.goto(url, { timeout: 60000, waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1024, height: 800 });
  await page.screenshot({
   path: "./screenshot.jpg",
   type: "jpeg",
   fullPage: true
 });
 await page.close();
 await browser.close();
})();
```